# Pytorch torch.cholesky ignoring exception

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

For some matrices on my batch I'm having an exception due the matrix being singular.

```
L = th.cholesky(Xt.bmm(X))
```

> cholesky_cpu: For batch 51100: U(22,22) is zero, singular U

Since they are few for my use case I would like to ignore the exception and further deal with them. I will set the resulting calculation as **nan** is it possible somehow?

Actually if I `catch` the exception and use `continue` still it doesn’t finish the calculation of the rest of the batch.

The same happens in C++ with Pytorch libtorch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to catch the exception according to [`Pytorch Discuss` forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-cholesky-ignoring-exception/69755/8).

The solution, unfortunately, was to **implement my own**  simple batched cholesky (`th.cholesky(..., upper=False)`) and then deal with Nan values using `th.isnan`.

```
import torch as th

# nograd cholesky
def cholesky(A):
    L = th.zeros_like(A)

    for i in range(A.shape[-1]):
        for j in range(i+1):
            s = 0.0
            for k in range(j):
                s = s + L[...,i,k] * L[...,j,k]

            L[...,i,j] = th.sqrt(A[...,i,i] - s) if (i == j) else \
                      (1.0 / L[...,j,j] * (A[...,i,j] - s))
    return L
```

Answer (score 1):

When performing cholesky decomposition PyTorch relies on LAPACK for CPU tensors and MAGMA for CUDA tensors. In the [PyTorch code used to call LAPACK](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/BatchLinearAlgebra.cpp#L465) the batch is just iterated over, invoking LAPACK's [`zpotrs_`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d8d/group__complex16_p_ocomputational_gaa2116ea574b01efda584dff0b74c9fcd.html#gaa2116ea574b01efda584dff0b74c9fcd) function on each matrix separately. In the [PyTorch code used to call MAGMA](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e1a895858f166a99dfd8a32b096dff4b270149ba/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/BatchLinearAlgebra.cu#L760) the entire batch is processed using MAGMA's [`magma_dpotrs_batched`](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/projectsfiles/magma/doxygen/group__magma__potrs__batched.html#ga7ba860509604deb097b36140a2e67661) which is probably faster than iterating over each matrix separately.

AFAIK there's no way to indicate to MAGMA or LAPACK to not raise exceptions (though to be fair, I'm not an expert on these packages). Since MAGMA may be exploiting batches in some way we may not want to just default to an iterative approach, since we are potentially losing performance by not performing the batched cholesky.

One potential solution is to first try and perform batched cholesky decomposition, if it fails then we could perform cholesky decomposition on each element in the batch, setting the entries that fail to NaN.

```
def cholesky_no_except(x, upper=False, force_iterative=False):
    success = False
    if not force_iterative:
        try:
            results = torch.cholesky(x, upper=upper)
            success = True
        except RuntimeError:
            pass

    if not success:
        # fall back to operating on each element separately
        results_list = []
        x_batched = x.reshape(-1, x.shape[-2], x.shape[-1])
        for batch_idx in range(x_batched.shape[0]):
            try:
                result = torch.cholesky(x_batched[batch_idx, :, :], upper=upper)
            except RuntimeError:
                # may want to only accept certain RuntimeErrors add a check here if that's the case
                # on failure create a "nan" matrix
                result = float('nan') + torch.empty(x.shape[-2], x.shape[-1], device=x.device, dtype=x.dtype)
            results_list.append(result)
        results = torch.cat(results_list, dim=0).reshape(*x.shape)

    return results
```

If you expect exceptions to be common during cholesky decomposition you may want use `force_iterative=True` to skip the initial call which tries to use the batched version, since in that case this function would likely just be wasting time with the first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this compares speed-wise to the other solutions posted, but it may be faster.

First use `torch.det` to determine if there are any singular matrices in your batch. Then mask out those matrices.

```
output = Xt.bmm(X)
dets = torch.det(output)

# if output is of shape (bs, x, y), dets will be of shape (bs)
bad_idxs = dets==0 #might want an allclose here

output[bad_idxs] = 1. # fill singular matrices with 1s

L = torch.cholesky(output)
```

After you probably need to deal with the singular matrices you filled in with 1s, but you have their index values so it's easy to grab them or exclude them.

Comment: Thank you @Karl I tried that. Unfortunately that is not faster than my own `cholesky` plus `th.isnan`. But really thanks for the willingness to help.